# how to declare a node import in typescript compiler to ignore it in compiled file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, axios, typescript-compiler-api

Hello while trying to understand `typescript` and the `typescript compiler` a little bit better i tried a little web project.

The workflow is simple. The `typescript compiler` watches the `src/js`folder and compiles every `*.ts`file into my `dev_static/js` folder  as a `*.js`file and also replicate  the folder structure.

From there my `django dev server` fetches the `*.js`files if necessary. For example `page_1.html` needs the script  `<script type="module" src="{% static 'js/pages/page_1.js' %}"> </script>`.

```
src/
   js/
      pages/page_1.ts
      pages/page_2.ts
      navbar/navbar.ts
      modules/some_modul.ts


dev_static/
          js/
            pages/page_1.js
            pages/page_2.js
            navbar/navbar.js
            modules/some_modul.js
```

**.tsconfig**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../dev_static/js",
        "removeComments": true,
        "target": "ES6",       
         "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2015.promise"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~*": ["./*"],
            "@node/*": ["./node_modules/*"]
        },
    },
    // Input Dir
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

---

### Problem

importing modules as ES6 works fine. But i am struggling to declare 3rd Party libraries like Axios in my typescript project. For Example to use the types and intellisense of axios i imported Axios as a Node Module like this:

### **axios_fetch.ts**

```
import axios from '@node/axios'; 
import { graphUrl } from '../env/env.js';
```

Compiler Output:

### **axios_fetch.js**

```
import axios from '@node/axios';
import { graphUrl } from '../env/env.js';
```

Of Course the Browser does not know how to resolve this: `import axios from '@node/axios';` .

```
2127.0.0.1/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@node/axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Furthermore i load the `axios` min.version (or other 3rd Party Libraries) global in my dev server. Its embedded in a base template on which every other page is based on and every page will have `<script type="module" src="{% static 'js/3rdParty/axios/axios.min.js' %}"> </script>` in it by default.

```
dev_static/
          js/
            pages/page_1.js
            <...>
            3rdParty/axios/axios.min.js
```

---

### Question

How can i tell the compiler not to compile the line `import axios from '@node/axios';` in my typescript file? Because the Axios Library will be available or loaded global as a minified version in all my pages (templates). I only need this line so that typescript does not complain and has the types available.

What i need is that the `typescript compiler` does not process the "import" line for axios while compiling. Or in other words i need that node import only in dev-compile-time for type checking, interface etc. but not in finished javascript file or runtime.

### **axios_fetch.ts**

```
    import axios from '@node/axios';// do not compile this. "axios" will be global available
    import { graphUrl } from '../env/env.js';
```

If i manually delete `import axios from '@node/axios';` in my `axios_fetch.js` this it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after some days of research i found this solution and it works for me.
Typescript no longer complains or exports the types `import` line into my compiled file, while still having access to types and intelisense in my `*.ts` file.

---

First i changed a bit in the `tsconfig.json` very important to declare `"importsNotUsedAsValues":"remove"`.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // Output Dir
        "outDir": "../dev_static/js",
        "removeComments": true,
        // Compile to. What JS Versions.
        "target": "ES6",       
         "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2015.promise"
        ],
        // allows also normal JS files
        "allowJs": true,
        // Normal JS file also be checked
        "checkJs": true,
        // important for import modules etc.
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importsNotUsedAsValues":"remove",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~*": ["./*"],
            "@node/*": ["./node_modules/*"]
        },   
         "types": ["axios"]

    },
    // Input Dir
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

---

Then i imported only the needed type from the axios nodes version and declared it as a global. But you can also simply download the  `index.d.ts` type file from the axios git repo  and put into your folder. Remove `"types": ["axios"]` from the `tsconfig` and import with `import {AxiosStatic} from './axios';`

In other words the first line imports `types` that i only need in this `*.ts`file but not later in my compiled  `*.js` file. The second import line imports a  `variable` called `graphUrl` as an ES6 Module, that reference on the other hand i will need later in my compiled file.

**axios_fetch.ts**

```
import { AxiosStatic } from 'axios'; // import the specific types from nodes axios 
import { graphUrl } from '../env/env.js'; // that some es6 module vars i need also later

declare global {
    const axios: AxiosStatic ;
} 

// AXIOS Client
export const clientA = axios.create({
    baseURL: graphUrl,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    } });
```

---

So by `declare global` typescript seems does not have to worry not to export `const axios: AxiosStatic` or to fulfill all type demands (`importsNotUsedAsValues`) because it now knows there will be a deposit on a global scale.

**axios_fetch.js**

```
import { graphUrl } from '../env/env.js';
const csrftoken = getCookie(cookieName);
export const clientA = axios.create({
    baseURL: graphUrl,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    }
});
```

Now have it compiled without the `import { AxiosStatic } from 'axios';` line of the types.